# Async Read server BoostAsio not calling handler

Tags: c++, boost, server, boost-asio

I'm currently working with Boost::Asio to do a basic Read/Write server, I have a little problem when it comes to the usage of the async_read function of the library.

Here's my code snippet :

**main.cpp** :

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include "TCPServer.hpp"
#include "TCPConnection.hpp"

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main()
{
  try
    {
      boost::asio::io_service io_service;
      TCPServer server(io_service);
      io_service.run();
    }
  catch (std::exception& e)
    {
      std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

**TCPServer.hpp :**

```
#ifndef TCPSERVER_HPP_
#define TCPSERVER_HPP_

#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include "TCPConnection.hpp"

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class TCPServer
{
private:
  tcp::acceptor _acceptor;

public:
  TCPServer(boost::asio::io_service& ioService)
    : _acceptor(ioService, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 4040))
  {
    startAccept();
  }

private:
  void startAccept()
  {
    TCPConnection::pointer newConnection =
      TCPConnection::create(_acceptor.get_io_service());
    _acceptor.async_accept(newConnection->getSocket(),
                           boost::bind(&TCPServer::handleAccept, this, newConnection,
                                       boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }

  void handleAccept(TCPConnection::pointer newConnection, const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error)
      {
        newConnection->asyncWrite("JIOLE");
        startAccept();
      }
  }
};

#endif
```

**TCPConnection.hpp :**

```
#ifndef TCPCONNECTION_HPP_
#define TCPCONNECTION_HPP_

#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

class TCPConnection : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<TCPConnection>
{
private:
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket _socket;
  std::string _readMessage;
  boost::asio::streambuf _response;

public:
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<TCPConnection> pointer;

  static pointer create(boost::asio::io_service& ios)
  {
    return pointer(new TCPConnection(ios));
  }

  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& getSocket()
  {
    return _socket;
  }

  void  asyncWrite(const std::string &message)
  {
    boost::asio::async_write(_socket,
                             boost::asio::buffer(message),
                             boost::bind(&TCPConnection::handleWrite, shared_from_this(),


    boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        std::cout << "AsyncWrite" << std::endl;
      }

  void asyncRead()
  {
    std::cout << "1st \"asyncRead\"" << std::endl;
    boost::asio::async_read(_socket,
                            _response,
                            boost::bind(&TCPConnection::handleRead, shared_from_this(),
                                        boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    std::cout << "2nd \"asyncRead\"" << std::endl;
  }

  void close()
  {
    _socket.close();
  }

private:

  TCPConnection(boost::asio::io_service &ioS) : _socket(ioS) {}

  void  handleWrite(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    std::cout << "Write Handler" << std::endl;
    if (!error)
      {
        asyncRead();
      }
    //SEE WHAT TO DO IN CASE OF ERROR                                                                                                                                                                                
  }

  void handleRead(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    std::cout << "Read Handler" << std::endl;
    if (!error)
      {
        std::cout << &_response << std::endl;
        asyncRead();
      }
    else
      {
        std::cout << &error << std::endl;
        _socket.close();
      }
    //CREATE SENDER(RSEPONSE::ERROR)                                                                                                                                                                                 
  }

};

#endif
```

The problem is that my async_read doesn't call the handler. Here is the output :

**Output :**

```
AsyncWrite
Write Handler
1st "asyncRead"
2nd "asyncRead"
```

When I'm writing something on a NetCat Client nothing is being received.

Here what happens when i'm pressing ctrl+C :

```
Read Handler
0x7fff645f3be0
```

I don't understand why nothing is received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you did not tell `async_read` **when** it should call the handler function. There are two ways to specify this: Either specify the input size after which the handler shall be called or specifiy a delimiter through [`async_read_until`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read_until/overload1.html).

In your case, you could use the following:

```
boost::asio::async_read_until(_socket,
                              _response,
                               "\n",
                               boost::bind(&TCPConnection::handleRead, 
                                           shared_from_this(),
                                           boost::asio::placeholders::error)
                             );
```

This will call the handler when a newline is sent from the client.

Comment: Note that it might read _more_ than up to the first delimiter (`recv` receives in chunks and there might be trailing data in the same chunk). Also, you can create (much) more advanced stop conditions by passing a functor, so you can have active logic determine when the message is complete.

Comment: If I may ask you one more thing @sehe, I'm receiving a basic text which hasn't got any "\n" at the end (And i can't change that fact) eg: "hello" how could  I know when to stop the read ?

Comment: Sounds like you can't. You should probably handle the EOF signal or study the protocol so you can predict the size of the message (e.g. like Content-Length in the HTTP protocol)